# Initializing an Array of Object Pointers to NULL

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hash, null

I have a project that requires creation of an array of object pointers which must be initialized to NULL by an init() method. Here is the code:

```
HashLin *primHash[10];

void HashPerfect:: init() {         //FIX ME
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    primHash[i] = NULL;
}
```

And I'm receiving the following error message when attempting to compile the code:

```
hashperfect.cpp: In member function 'void HashPerfect::init()':
hashperfect.cpp:17:15: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 1 of 
'HashLin::HashLin(int)' [Wconversion-null]
primHash[i] = NULL;
            ^
```

I feel like this could be something to do with my the constructor of class HashLin, but I'm not sure. If that would help diagnose the problem, here are the constructors for class HashLin:

```
HashLin::HashLin(){
    //size = 0;
    hashTable = vector<string>(1);
    init();
};

HashLin::HashLin(int mySize){

    hashTable = vector<string>(mySize);

    init();
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

My intention is to create an array of pointers to HashLin objects - here is the code for the HashLin object class...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "HashLin.hpp"
using namespace std;


bool success;
vector<string> hashTable;

void HashLin:: init() {
    //hashTable = vector<string>(1);
    for (int i=0; i<hashTable.size(); i++)
        hashTable[i] = "";
}       

int HashLin:: hashMe(string myString) {

    //char foo[] = myString;


    char *s = new char[(myString.length())];
    unsigned int hash;
    for (hash = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hash = 37*hash + *s;

    hash = hash % hashTable.size();


    return hash;

}





    HashLin::HashLin(){
        //size = 0;
        hashTable = vector<string>(1);
        init();
    };

    HashLin::HashLin(int mySize){

        hashTable = vector<string>(mySize);

        init();
    };

    bool HashLin:: insert(string insertMe){
        //hashMe(insertMe);
        int hashVal = hashMe(insertMe);

        success = false;
        int count = 0;

        while (hashVal < hashTable.size() && success==false && 
count<hashTable.size()) {

            if (hashTable[hashVal] == ""){
                hashTable[hashVal] = insertMe;
                success = true;
            }
            else if (hashVal == hashTable.size()-1)
                hashVal = 0;
            else{
                hashVal++;
                count++;
            }   


        }

        if (count == hashTable.size())
            cout << "Failed to Hash: " << insertMe << endl;
        return success;
    }

    void HashLin:: printOut(){

        for (int i=0; i<hashTable.size(); i++){
            cout << i << ": " << hashTable[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    int HashLin:: getSize(){
        return hashTable.size();

    }

    bool HashLin:: getSuccess(){
        return success;

    }

    void HashLin:: setSize(int toSet){
        hashTable.resize(toSet);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`.

Comment: None of that code should invoke the constructor of `HashLin`. Post all *real* code required for *us* to produce your error. Your posted code appears to be using `HashLin primHash[10];` (i.e. an array of instances, not an array of pointers), then using a conversion construction to a temporary prior to the assignment.

Comment: @JesperJuhl my instructor has explicitly told us to use NULL, not nullptr.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not quite sure what you're saying but I'm happy to post more code. I am intending to create an array of pointers - is that not what I'm doing here? still pretty new to c++

Comment: @Nate: WhozCraig is pointing out that you are not posting the actual code. The code you posted defines 10 pointers. The error message appears to be from code which defined `primHash[]` as an array of objects. We can't help if you're not posting the actual code you tried to compile.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the Objects to nullptr instead:
`primHash[i] = nullptr`

Comment: that hasn't worked for me either, and my instructor has explicity said to use "NULL"

Comment: my compiler tells me "nullptr hasn't been declared in this scope" when I've tried it

Comment: @Nate: Your instructor is not up to date. `nullptr` replaced `NULL` 7 years ago. That said, there's probably more wrong with the course looking at your question.